# Не двигается снаряд. Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-android, unity3d-editor

Я не могу сделать так, чтобы объект двигался в точку тапа. :( Он появляется и зависает в точке появления.

Единственная ошибка - не не может найти Rigitbody, если прописать его только в скрипте пули (PoolsObject). Если же этот компонент искать в Attack, ошибки нет.

**Это скрипт движения пуль. Призывает объект в точку и говорит, куда им плыть (вернее, должен был бы говорить об этом, но нет).**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Attack : MonoBehaviour
{
    // ОПИСАНИЕ ДВИЖЕНИЯ ПУЛЬ

    public GameObject container, empty;
    RaycastHit hit;
    Rigidbody rb;
    public int damage = 1;
    private Vector3 direction;
    private bool isTouched;

    //У призванного объекта берём Риджитбоди (я знаю, что можно без этого, он не работает ни в каком случае).
    private void Start()
    {
        rb = Call().GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }


    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        //Ищем тык.
        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
            Ray ray = GetComponent<Camera>().ScreenPointToRay(touch.position);
            //Вычисляем путь призванного объекта.
            if (Call() != null)
            {
                if (Physics.Raycast(Call().gameObject.transform.position, ray.direction, out hit, Mathf.Infinity))
                {
                    Debug.Log(hit.point);
                    Debug.DrawRay(Call().transform.position, ray.direction);


                    if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began && !isTouched)
                    {
                        Physics.SyncTransforms();
                        isTouched = true;
                        Invoke(nameof(Call), 0.1f);
                        direction = ray.direction - Call().transform.position;
                        Call().gameObject.transform.GetComponent<PoolsObject>().Movement(direction, rb);
                        isTouched = false;

                    }

                }
            }
        }



      
    }


    //Просто призыв пули из пула.

    private PoolsObject Call()
    {

        PoolsObject whizbang = container.GetComponent<Pool>().GetFreeElement(empty.transform.position);
        return whizbang;
    }


}
```

**Код на самом снаряде.**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]
public class PoolsObject : MonoBehaviour
{

    public int speed = 10;

    //Возвращение в пул.
    public void Return ()
    {
        gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }


    private void Update()
    {
        if (gameObject.activeInHierarchy)
        {
            Invoke(nameof(Return), 5f);
        }

    }

    //Движение пули.

    public void Movement (Vector3 direction, Rigidbody rb)
    {
        
        rb.velocity = direction * speed * Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

**Код пула (на всякий случай).**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Pool : MonoBehaviour
{
    private List<PoolsObject> bullets;
    public PoolsObject bullet;
    public int bulletPool;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Awake()
    {
        bullets = new List<PoolsObject>();

        InstantiateBullet();
    }

    private void InstantiateBullet()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < bulletPool; i++)
        {
            CreateBullet(false);
        }

    }

    private PoolsObject CreateBullet(bool isActiveByDefault = false)
    {
        var creation = Instantiate(bullet, gameObject.transform);
        bullets.Add(creation);
        creation.gameObject.SetActive(isActiveByDefault);
        return creation;
    }

    public bool TryGetBullet(out PoolsObject poolsObject)
    {
        foreach (var bullet in bullets)
        {
            if (!bullet.gameObject.activeInHierarchy)
            {
                poolsObject = bullet;
                bullet.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                return true;
            }
        }

        poolsObject = null;
        return false;
    }

    public PoolsObject GetFreeElement()
    {
        if (TryGetBullet(out var poolsObject))
        {
            return poolsObject;
        }
        else return CreateBullet(true);
    }

    public PoolsObject GetFreeElement(Vector3 position)
    {
        if (TryGetBullet(out var poolsObject))
        {
            poolsObject.transform.position = position;
            return poolsObject;
        }
        else return CreateBullet(true);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, поменял MovePosition на AddForce, сделал так, чтобы AddForce прикладывал силу по вектору Raycast (из камеры в точку тапа). Но даже так AddForce будет шмалять во все стороны, поэтому в снаряде в Rigidbody увеличил значение Drag до десяти.

А, и для полной честности, сделал так, чтобы стрельба шла из точки касания пальцем экрана (то есть, из Канваса).